# Integration by part questions

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, weak-derivatives

I'm currently reading Evans' Partial Differential Equation, and I have some questions regarding Integration by parts.
So we need an open bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $C^1$ boundary to apply integration by part on a function $u\in C^1(\bar{U})$.
But I notice in definition of weak derivative, Evans makes no reference to the boundary of open sets. And also in a lot of proof, he makes no use of the boundary.
I want to ask that for weak derivatives, do we not care about whether the open set has $C^1$ boundary? Do we only care about if $\int_{U}uD^\alpha\phi dx = (-1)^{|\alpha|}\int_{U}D^\alpha u\phi dx$ ?

Answer (score 1):

The definition of a weak derivative is that $D^\alpha u$ is a weak $\alpha$-derivative of $u$ if

$$\tag{1} \int_{U}uD^\alpha\phi dx = (-1)^{|\alpha|}\int_{U}D^\alpha u\phi dx$$

for all smooth functions $\varphi : \Omega \to \mathbb R$ **with compact support**, hence $\varphi$ is zero at the boundary $\partial \Omega$ of $\Omega$. In particular, if $u$ is smooth (so that the weak derivatives coincide with the classical one), then (1) holds for all such $\varphi$ and the boundary values of $u$ is irrelevant.

Comment: Suppose u is smooth but the boundary is not piecewise C1, how do we know the weak derivative is equal to classical derivative? We cannot use integration by part without knowing how the boundary behaves. But I think if for any compact subset of open set, we can find an open set in between that has C1 boundary, then we can resolve this. Is this claim generally true?

Comment: I think this claim is true because we can take finite ball cover that is compactly contained in the larger open set by compactness of the support, so the union has piecewise smooth boundary. Is this justification enough?

Comment: @Frozer Clark We can use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2699479/finding-a-domain-with-c1-boundary to justify your idea.